# how to compare values in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

this is the html code

```
   <html>
        <head>
            <title>Halaman Awal</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
                <a [routerLink]="['/databuku']"><img src="images/images.png" width="42" height="42"></a>
            </nav>
        <div class="container-fluid text-center pb-5">
          <div style="text-align:center">
            <h1>
              Welcome!
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form (ngSubmit)="login()">
            <div class="form-group">
                Username
                <input class="validate" type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="dataUser.username" required>
            </div> 
            <div class ="form-group">
                Password
                <input class="validate" type="text" name="password" [(ngModel)]="dataUser.password" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
            </div>

        </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

this is the ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hlm-utama',
  templateUrl: './hlm-utama.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hlm-utama.component.css']
})
export class HlmUtamaComponent implements OnInit {

  dataUser={};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  } 

  login() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/user')
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.dataUser = data;
        this.router.navigate(['/databuku/']);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

}
```

so I already have table that have username and password data in database table "dataUser", now I want to compare the data that I input with data in my database table. If its the same, it will execute the login(), if it fails it is not doing anything or at least still in that page, so how to do that?

I don't understand how to do the authentication function or anything, please tell me the simple one

Comment: You need to send the credentials (i.e. `dataUser`) to your server, using a post rather than a get. The server will then check the credentials that has nothing to do with ANgular), and send back either a successfull response (200 or 204) or an error response (401).

Comment: where do I put the if function? in html or ts

Comment: To send and receive data from data base to your angular App, You need to implement some kind of back-end techniques, Learn the most suitable back-end technique and implement that.

Comment: is it in the controller or the user class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing your input data against expected values should be a responsibility of the server side implementation. I assume your are using basic authentication.

In very basic terms, you just pass username/password to backend and validate there and return success/fail response, but theres more to it. Following tutorial would be helpful to understand.

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial